# Showing and hiding my PyQt app in tray doesn't behave as it should

Tags: python, pyqt

So I created a system tray menu where I'd like to have the options to hide the app (to tray), quit it and show it (open the main window).

For some reason, I was able to hide the app by adding a the `self.win.hide()` command in my function but I'm not able to make it work in my tray menu.

So this is my main window:

[image]

This is the tray menu:

[image]

So I have a total of 3 issues currently. Two are with the tray menu:

1. When I click on "hide", nothing happens.
2. When I hide it using the "minimize" button, I then try to click on "show" to show the main window again, but all I see is this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QApplication, QMainWindow, QMenu, QStyle, QSystemTrayIcon
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import sys
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
import itertools
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

DURATION_INT = 10
toaster = ToastNotifier()
TIME_CYCLER = itertools.cycle([10, 5])  # 10 minutes, 10 seconds

def secs_to_minsec(secs: int):
    mins = secs // 60
    secs = secs % 60
    minsec = f'{mins:02}:{secs:02}'
    return minsec


class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.current_timer = 1
        self.time_left_int = DURATION_INT
        self.myTimer = QtCore.QTimer(self)

        # Init QSystemTrayIcon
        self.tray_icon = QSystemTrayIcon(self)
        self.tray_icon.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_ComputerIcon))

        #Tray menu
        show_action = QAction("Show", self)
        quit_action = QAction("Exit", self)
        hide_action = QAction("Hide", self)
        show_action.triggered.connect(self.show)
        hide_action.triggered.connect(self.hide)
        quit_action.triggered.connect(app.quit)
        tray_menu = QMenu()
        tray_menu.addAction(show_action)
        tray_menu.addAction(hide_action)
        tray_menu.addAction(quit_action)
        self.tray_icon.setContextMenu(tray_menu)
        self.tray_icon.show()

        # App window
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.win = QMainWindow()
        self.win.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 200)
        self.win.setWindowTitle("test")

        # Widgets
        self.titleLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.win)
        self.titleLabel.setText("Welcome to my app")
        self.titleLabel.move(50,20)

        self.timerLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.win)
        self.timerLabel.move(50,50)
        self.timerLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.timerLabel.setStyleSheet("font: 10pt Helvetica")

        self.startButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.win)
        self.startButton.setText("Start")
        self.startButton.move(50,100)
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.startTimer)

        self.minimizeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.win)
        self.minimizeButton.setText("Minimize")
        self.minimizeButton.move(50,130)
        self.minimizeButton.clicked.connect(self.minimize)

        self.update_gui()

        # Show window
        self.win.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def startTimer(self):
        self.time_left_int = next(TIME_CYCLER)
        self.myTimer.timeout.connect(self.timerTimeout)
        self.myTimer.start(1000)

    def timerTimeout(self):
        self.time_left_int -= 1
        if self.time_left_int == 0:
            if self.current_timer == 1:
                toaster.show_toast("test1", "test1", duration=3, threaded=True)
                self.current_timer = 2
            elif self.current_timer == 2:
                toaster.show_toast("test2", "test2", duration=3, threaded=True)
                self.current_timer = 1
            self.time_left_int = next(TIME_CYCLER)

        self.update_gui()

    def update_gui(self):
        minsec = secs_to_minsec(self.time_left_int)
        self.timerLabel.setText(minsec)

    def minimize(self):
        self.win.hide()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        event.ignore()
        self.win.hide()
        self.tray_icon.showMessage(
            "Tray Program",
            "Application was minimized to Tray",
            QSystemTrayIcon.Information,
            2000
        )

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
main_window = App()
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The 3rd issue that is not related to the tray menu is that whenever I click on the "exit" button, the app is minimized to tray and is hidden, but the popup message doesn't show for some reason. Which is weird because if I'll click on "show" after it has been minimized, then click on "X" again, it will just keep showing the popup message on each click. Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: remove `self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)` and `sys.exit(app.exec_())` in \__init__, is useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t have the `win10toast` module, so I commented out some lines and marked them with
  `# win10toast`  -  uncomment them.

I don’t understand why you are creating the `self.win` object ?  Try it like this:

```
import sys
import itertools
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QApplication, QMainWindow, QMenu, QStyle, QSystemTrayIcon
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

#from win10toast import ToastNotifier                                      # win10toast

DURATION_INT = 10
#toaster = ToastNotifier()                                                 # win10toast
TIME_CYCLER = itertools.cycle([10, 5])  

def secs_to_minsec(secs: int):
    mins = secs // 60
    secs = secs % 60
    minsec = f'{mins:02}:{secs:02}'
    return minsec


class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.current_timer = 1
        self.time_left_int = DURATION_INT
        self.myTimer = QtCore.QTimer(self)

        # Init QSystemTrayIcon
        self.tray_icon = QSystemTrayIcon(self)
        self.tray_icon.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_ComputerIcon))

        #Tray menu
        show_action = QAction("Show", self)
        quit_action = QAction("Exit", self)
        hide_action = QAction("Hide", self)
        show_action.triggered.connect(self.show)
        hide_action.triggered.connect(self.hide)
        quit_action.triggered.connect(app.quit)

        tray_menu = QMenu()
        tray_menu.addAction(show_action)
        tray_menu.addAction(hide_action)
        tray_menu.addAction(quit_action)
        self.tray_icon.setContextMenu(tray_menu)
        self.tray_icon.show()

        # App window
# ?       self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
# ?       self.win = QMainWindow()
# ?       self.win.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 200)
# ?       self.win.setWindowTitle("test")
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 200)                                           # +++
        self.setWindowTitle("test")                                                    # +++

        # Widgets
        self.titleLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self) #.win)
        self.titleLabel.setText("Welcome to my app")
        self.titleLabel.move(50,20)

        self.timerLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self) #.win)
        self.timerLabel.move(50,50)
        self.timerLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.timerLabel.setStyleSheet("font: 10pt Helvetica")

        self.startButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self) #.win)
        self.startButton.setText("Start")
        self.startButton.move(50,100)
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.startTimer)

        self.minimizeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self) #.win)
        self.minimizeButton.setText("Minimize")
        self.minimizeButton.move(50,130)
        self.minimizeButton.clicked.connect(self.minimize)

        self.update_gui()

        # Show window
# ?       self.win.show()
# ?       sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def startTimer(self):
        self.time_left_int = next(TIME_CYCLER)
        self.myTimer.timeout.connect(self.timerTimeout)
        self.myTimer.start(1000)

    def timerTimeout(self):
        self.time_left_int -= 1
        if self.time_left_int == 0:
            if self.current_timer == 1:
#                toaster.show_toast("test1", "test1", duration=3, threaded=True)    # win10toast
                self.current_timer = 2
            elif self.current_timer == 2:
#                toaster.show_toast("test2", "test2", duration=3, threaded=True)    # win10toast
                self.current_timer = 1
            self.time_left_int = next(TIME_CYCLER)

        self.update_gui()

    def update_gui(self):
        minsec = secs_to_minsec(self.time_left_int)
        self.timerLabel.setText(minsec)

    def minimize(self):
# ?       self.win.hide()
        self.hide()                                                                  # +++


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        event.ignore()
# ?       self.win.hide()
        self.hide()                                                                  # +++
        self.tray_icon.showMessage(
            "Tray Program",
            "Application was minimized to Tray",
            QSystemTrayIcon.Information,
            2000
        )

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
main_window = App()
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]